# Is an intermittently beeping HDD normal?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, hard-drive-failure

I recently bought a [3TB Toshiba DT01ACA300](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B009AYWYOC/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A1R111JYQQ0J9G&th=1) HDD from Amazon. All I've done so far is connect the drive and initialise it, but in the few months it's been connected to my computer I've noticed that it intermittently makes beeping noises - 2-3 second long, barely audible but definitive beeps that are definitely coming from the HDD. These beeps seem to be relatively rare, occurring maybe once every few days - or maybe I just don't hear them all.

What could this mean for a new HDD that has barely been touched? Can such beeping be expected functionality for a HDD, or is it a a good enough reason to initiate an RMA?

Update: Crystal Disk Smartinfo [reveals no reallocated sectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zyDD.jpg).

Comment: As ever, the users of this site generous with the downvotes but not so much with the explanations for why. Am I expected to be clairvoyant?

Comment: Is it similar to the noises linked from http://www.datacent.com/hard_drive_sounds.php ? If so, which?

Comment: It seems to be an opinion based question. It’s not easy to say what noises are normal for your particular make and model of hard drive. What I consider beeping may not be what you consider beeping. In my opinion, no hard drive should be making a beeping noise.

Comment: @Hashim does the hard disk stay connected when it beeps? Or does it reconnect?

Comment: @Appleoddity It'd be opinion-based if I was asking whether my HDD was dead. The question as I worded it in the second paragraph and in the title is a yes or no - can such beeping ever be expected functionality (i.e. normal) for a HDD, or is it always indicative of a fault? Certain users not knowing the answer to a question doesn't make it opinion-based, all it takes is someone with adequate experience of the hardware to weigh in.

Comment: @K7AAY The beep I hear sounds very similar to the first Hitachi laptop beep, although the drive is a desktop Toshiba, and the beep is a few seconds longer and occurs long after spinning up.

Comment: @K7AAY No clicks.

Comment: @K7AAY CDI screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/WfQZhuw.

Answer (score 4):

Please check S.M.A.R.T.. If the data show something wrong, that mean something wrong, simply. The main point if the disk made reallocation of own sectors because some damage.
The sound isn't a normal situation, I think, especially if it is really  strange but this is controversial and based on a personal experience. However, I have no idea what kind of sound is. I have 750 GB Toshiba on my notebook and it can be noisy sometimes but the disk is fine by the way, after 2 years. Another one is Blue WD and it can make some noise as starting to spin first time. However I can't say the same about 1 TB Toshiba or 4 TB Green WD, their sound isn't uncomfortable, this silent as is possible for HDD.
If I need silence, I choice SSD. Anyway it is probably fine as long as the data shows no errors. But I can't recommend you save something important on that unless 1 year later because if after that time you have no error, that mean highly likely you have no error another 4.

Comment: SMART is reporting everything as fine, but SMART generally tends to report only on metrics like whether reading and writing has failed and whether sectors have gone bad, which are unlikely to show problems on a drive that has never had data on it. I can't see how SMART would determine whether a HDD's mechanics or firmware is failing.